# Is there a SwiftUI version of the UIKit UIButton.ButtonType.close?

Tags: ios, swift, button, swiftui, uikit

Right now, I am in the process of converting from UIKit to SwiftUI. In UIKit, there is a native [Close, X-Styled Button](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/buttontype/close/) - `UIButton.ButtonType.close,` like shown below:

[image]

I wanted to find the equivalent of this in SwiftUI, if built in to SwiftUI already. It is understandable if Apple hasn't gotten around to building/converting this yet. I see this also in the Apple Maps App, which I believe is built in SwiftUI, like shown below (on the bottom right corner of the panel):

[image]

If there isn't a built in button styling, how would one go about creating a View for this close button, which would adapt to light and dark mode? Thank you so much!

Edit: In UIKIt's Storyboard Editor, here is what I am looking for:

[image]

Comment: Did you check SFSymbols?

Comment: Yes I have, it does not quite fit what I am looking for. Here is an image to help show what I mean:
[https://assets.cdn.awesomeplayer.tech/img/images/1676599524_08:20:48am-2022-08-10.png](https://assets.cdn.awesomeplayer.tech/img/images/1676599524_08:20:48am-2022-08-10.png)

Comment: @koen, I was able to tinker around in SFSymbols a bit more to find something very similar - thank you so much!:
[https://assets.cdn.awesomeplayer.tech/img/images/1154950817_08:26:26am-2022-08-10.png](https://assets.cdn.awesomeplayer.tech/img/images/1154950817_08:26:26am-2022-08-10.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SwiftUI does not use concept of "button type", instead you can construct it by yourself, like

```
Button(action: {}) {
    Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")   // << base !!
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 32, height: 32) // << for demo
        .foregroundColor(.gray)
}
```

*with any other modifiers as you wish

[image: demo]

Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Answer (score 6):

You can embed a UIKit `UIButton` with `UIViewRepresentable`.

```swift
struct CloseButton: UIViewRepresentable {
    private let action: () -> Void
    
    init(action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.action = action
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton(type: .close)
        button.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.perform), for: .primaryActionTriggered)
        return button
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIButton, context: Context) {
        context.coordinator.action = action
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(action: action)
    }
    
    class Coordinator {
        var action: () -> Void
        
        init(action: @escaping () -> Void) {
            self.action = action
        }
        
        @objc func perform() {
            action()
        }
    }
}
```

and then

```swift
CloseButton {
    // dismiss()
}
```

Example:

```swift
SomeView()
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
            CloseButton {
                dismiss()
            }
            .disabled(isBusy) // SwiftUI modifiers work fine.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

It is not currently possible to use system button types in SwiftUI including the close button. I’ve submitted FB10380135 to request this addition.

In the meantime, you could make a Button look like the system close button. Mike Stern, an Apple Design Evangelist, noted in an Ask Apple Q&A:

> The modal close button uses the "xmark" SF Symbol at 15pt bold
> (regular size symbol, not large or small variant) and a 30×30pt
> circle. The hit area is likely bigger as we typically go for at target
> size that's at least 44×44pt.

Also note the close button doesn’t change size as the dynamic type size increases/decreases. Do be sure to make its accessibility label “close” and add support for the large content viewer so people using accessibility text sizes can tap and hold the button to reveal a large xmark symbol with the word Close underneath.

I personally would recommend utilizing `UIViewRepresentable` to add a real close `UIButton` button though as opposed to trying to replicate it exactly - see the answer provided by MMP0.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `xmark.circle.fill` symbol as the system image:

[image: XMARK]

⚠️ Note: there is a difference between `xmark.circle.fill` and `x.circle.fill`